# Azure Users Shared Between Accounts

Tags: azure, active-directory, single-sign-on, azure-active-directory

I'm making an app for a business where all the employees of the company should be able to sign in.

Employees have an account in `Azure Active Directory` (in the company's Azure Account ofc.) and add them as users to my API App as if they were users from my AAD (copying them is not an option).

Is how I'm describing it possible?

I have been looking into things like `Single-Sign-On`, `B2B`, but haven't quite understood neither of them.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Yes it is possible.

You can invite their users as guests into your Azure AD, and then you will be able to assign them access to apps in your tenant.

I assume you have some kind of front-end for your API?
After they have redeemed the invite and you have granted them access, they will be able to login through your front-end as if they were users in your AAD tenant.
Be sure to use the tenant-specific login endpoint though, since if you use the "common" endpoint, they'll login against their own AAD tenant.

Comment: My question wasn't clear, my bad. I need to give 400 users access to my app. The user isn't going to use the api, the app is. I just need to use their credentials so I can require an OAuth access_token for the api - from the api. I can't manually invite everyone of them since they might get deleted as a user etc. (and it would take way too long)

Comment: Then what you have is a multi-tenant app, though you will need to restrict which tenants you actually allow. In this case you'll need to make the app multi-tenanted, and have an admin from their tenant login to your app, which should then enable it for use in their tenant. Then any of their users would be able to login to your app. You'd need to change to use the common AAD endpoint, and validate the issuer of the tokens such that it is either your or their tenant.

Comment: Thank you! I'll give it a go !

Comment: Hope another question is alright in the same thread :). I would need to add the admin of the other tenant as a guest so that he can grant permission for the other users in their tenant?

Comment: No. I suggest you read up on the multi-tenant pattern here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-convert-app-to-be-multi-tenant. Their admin logs in with their account on their tenant, enabling users in their tenant to start using the app.